# Run functions on elements with a certain class as soon as the DOM is loaded, not using an event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, document-ready

I have a simple function which I want to run on all elements with a certain class. I want this function to be run as soon as the DOM is loaded; not upon an event handler.

Below is the code that will run on an event handler like hover. How do I make it run as soon as the DOM is loaded?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var displayname = $(".displayname");

    function alignSpans(){
        var spanheight = this.offsetHeight;
        var cssbottom = spanheight + "px";
        this.style.bottom = cssbottom; 
    }

    displayname.hover(alignSpans);

});
```

`displayname.alignSpans();` does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `displayname` is a jQuery object, you can use [`.each()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each) to call a callback function using `this` as the contained DOM elements (which is very conveniently the same convention as an event handler)

```
displayname.each(alignSpans);
```

Comment: gnarf's answer is the simplest. If you wanted it to work with the format `displayname.alignSpans();` then you would need to create your `alignSpans` function as a jQuery plugin, i.e. adding it as a property to `$.fn`.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the .each() function is for. I've made your code a bit more efficient too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".displayname").each(function() {
        $(this).css("bottom", $(this).height()); 
    });
});
```

Comment: jQuery will actually automatically add `px` if you just pass in `$(this).height()`

Comment: That's good to know. I took out it (neat code is so much better...)